# How do I remove iSCSI targets from Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi

Windows Server 2012R2 machine which used to connect to an iSCSI target (which no longer exists).  We've been having periodic crashes of this Windows Server only to find that the iSCSI initiator is continually trying to reconnect to that long gone target (and causing eventual resource exhaustion).  I've removed the discovered target in the initiator and the drive letter through disk management, but on rebooting the target reappears in the initiator (and starts us down the path of resource exhaustion once again).

How do I tell Windows to stop trying to reconnect to this long gone iSCSI target?

Comment: Did you remove from the 'Favorite Targets'?

Comment: That's got it!  I was thinking the favorites tab was like a browser favorites, did not make the association with it being something that would auto-reconnect on every boot!  Thanks!

Comment: The issue is described in Microsoft support site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967476/iscsi-favorite-targets-may-need-to-be-re-created-if-there-is-a-network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 'Favorite Targets' - this *sticky* the targets to attempt the mount.